# .Net Core Dependencies - Bower

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have problem with `bower.json` 
When I created new project in .net core I have error:

[image]

My `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6"
  }
}
```

I haven been looking for solution but I didn't found any.

I reinstalled bower with:

```
npm uninstall -g bower
npm install -g bower
```

My Settings:[image]

In wwwroot/lib I can find jquery and bootstrap but the error still does not disappear.

Comment: The syntax of your bower.json looks fine. Please check in Visual Studio the output window "Bower/npm" while restoring the packages. Do you see any messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Install bower with an admin shell and push the $(PATH) to the second place in your "External Web Tools".

Bower should install in the directory (Standard)

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

Check in a command window:

`where bower`